# I have a huge music archive on a remote server. How can I set up a page that lets people interact with it?

Tags: file, directory, structure, archive, interactive

What I want to have is some sort of file tree that people can interact with and download songs or folders of songs.  I kinda got started with a file listing PHP script ([which you can see here](http://mlpmusicarchive.com/archive/full/)) but it requires me to copy the same index.php to every individual folder.  I would be okay with this if I knew how to copy the same file to every subdirectory in the archive.

What do you guys think? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you do is to use your webserver to browse the file hierarchy. But what you want is to use your script (the index.php). So instead of creating links that point to a deeper place in your file system, create links that point to your index.php, but add a parameter that tells the script the (relative) folder. Beware that you have to verify that only files can be shown that you actually want to make public (i.e. no files above your "entry" directory).

Comment: and since you're new here: don't forget to upvote and mark correct answers ;D